# Python os.walk netCDF4 not working together

Tags: python, netcdf, os.walk

I am trying to go through a series of .nc files to run a small bit of code. The test script below prints the first filename in the directory but when I use `ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(fname, 'r')`  I get the error

```
File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", 
line 1795, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__ 
(netCDF4\_netCDF4.c:12278)
    RuntimeError: No such file or directory
```

Is this an incompatibility issue with os.walk and netCDF4 or is it a simple error I am making?

```
import os
import netCDF4

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('E:\satellite .nc data\ENVISAT2006'):
   for fname in files:
       print fname # works up to here and without line below it prints all filenames 
       ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(fname, 'r')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was a simple problem of needing the path and directory in

`ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(fname, 'r')`

so I have replaced it with

`ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(os.path.join(fdir,fname), 'r')`

and specified `fdir` outside the loop. For simplicity I have replaced `os.walk` with `os.listdir` as I don't need to go through a directory tree.

```
import os
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
from math import pi
from numpy import cos, sin

fdir = 'E:\satellite .nc data\ENVISAT2006'
for fname in os.listdir('E:\satellite .nc data\ENVISAT2006'):
#os.walk only needed if going through all of the files in a directory tree
   #for fname in files:
    print fname 
    ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(os.path.join(fdir,fname), 'r')
```